# Random.nextInt() unresolved reference

Tags: kotlin, random

I get unresolved reference on either
`Random`
or `.nextInt()`
when using any of those imports `import java.util.* import kotlin.random.*`
on Android Studio with Kotlin.

I've used both `import java.util.*` and
`import kotlin.random.*` and the unresolved reference error appears on either the Class or the method. How do I import Kotlin.random properly?

Answer (score 1):

`kotlin.random` and its associated classes are actually included in [the Kotlin standard library](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/), so your existing reference should be working:

```
import kotlin.random.Random;

fun main() {
    println(Random.nextInt())
}
```

What it sounds like is that the appropriate references/libraries for Kotlin and/or Java aren't being properly loaded for your project. Depending on your environment (e.g. Gradle, Maven, etc.), you may want to force a compile or install step to ensure the dependencies are available.